# How to handle empty rows in CROSS APPLY [SQL Server]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cross-apply, nul

I've below `Stored Procedure`-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Optimized_GetArticlePostAMP]                                                              
(                                                                                    
 @PostID int                                                                                    
)                                                                                          

AS                                                                                    
BEGIN                                                                                    
SET NOCOUNT ON;                                                                                    
SET STATISTICS TIME ON                                                    

DECLARE @SectionId int ,@datediff int                                            
DECLARE @postdate datetime

 SELECT P.PostId, P.SectionID, P.PostName,MP.MetaTitle,P.Postdate,P.PostAuthor,P.IsApproved,                                                                                             
 MP.Metadescription, MP.Metakeywords,ISNULL(MP.IsRobotsMetaTag,0) as IsRobotsMetaTag,p.TotalViews, P.Subject, P.FormattedBody,                                                                                               
 MV.Isvideo,MV.VideoCode,MV.VideoCaption, A.DrComment,A.SpanishURL, PS.RedirectUrl, Isnull(PS.IsRedirect,0) as IsRedirect,                                     
 ISNULL(A.CommentedBy,38633) as CommentedBy ,MP.Canonical as Canonical,ISNULL(MP.RRpopUP ,0) as RRpopUP,ISNULL(A.PrevPost,0) as PreviousPostId,        
 ISNULL(A.NextPost,0) as NextPostId,PS.StatusId ,dbo.[mercola_GetCommentCountForPost](@PostId) as TotalReplies, isnull(PA.[FileName],'') as FileName,         
 PRD.StoryImage, PRD.StoryContent, ISNULL(NULLIF(prd.ALT, ''), P.Subject) AS ALT, ISNULL(PR.ReferenceData,'')as ReferenceData,       
 MH.LastModifiedDate,    
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('<p><strong>By', FormattedBody, -1)=1 THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CAST(FormattedBody as varchar(max)),'<p><strong>By ',''),0,CHARINDEX('<',REPLACE(cast(FormattedBody as varchar(max)),'<p><strong>By ',''))))   
 ELSE 'Dr.Mercola' END as Name  
 FROM cs_posts P        
 LEFT JOIN Mercola_NewsletterDetails A on (P.Postid = A.postid)                                                                                       
 LEFT JOIN Mercola_PostStatus PS on (PS.postid=p.postid)                                                    
 LEFT JOIN Mercola_PostMetatags MP on(P.postid=MP.Postid)                                                                                             
 LEFT JOIN Mercola_postVideo MV  on(P.postid=MV.Postid)                                                      
 LEFT JOIN CS_PostAttachments PA on P.PostId=PA.PostId AND PA.contenttype LIKE 'audio/mpeg' AND PA.FILENAME LIKE '%.mp3' AND PA.isremote = 1                                                    
 LEFT JOIN Mercola_PostRelatedData PRD on P.PostId=PRD.PostId                                                  
 LEFT JOIN Mercola_PostReferences PR on P.PostId=PR.PostId        
 CROSS APPLY (select top 1 LastModifiedDate from Mercola_ArticleModifiedHistory where Mercola_ArticleModifiedHistory.Postid = P.postid order by LastModifiedDate desc)MH                                                  
 where P.Postid = @Postid
```

Now, when I `execute` the above `SP` with the below `PostID` -

`--[Mercola_Optimized_GetArticlePostAMP] 732490` I get the below data which is `expected`. As, the query inside `cross apply` has data for the above `postID`.

[image]

But now, when I `execute` the same `SP` with below different `PostID` -

`--[Mercola_Optimized_GetArticlePostAMP] 40702` I get below `empty data [rows]`. As, the query inside `cross apply` does not have the data for the above `postID` Infact, other `joins` have the data.

[image]

**Expected Result for above case -**
Return the data and assigning default value for the `CROSS APPLY`. How can I do it?

Comment: Use `OUTER APPLY` instead

Comment: @gofr1 Thanks, it worked. But now i want to assign default value when it does not have data..

Comment: I formalize all in one answer. Please, see below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY`

To overrun NULLs use `ISNULL(MH.LastModifiedDate, @DefaultValue) as LastModifiedDate`

Answer (score 3):

Change your query to  Outer Apply which will preserve  the rows from left hand side even if there are no matches

```
   outer APPLY (select top 1 LastModifiedDate
    from ArticleModifiedHistory 
    where ArticleModifiedHistory.Postid = P.postid order by LastModifiedDate desc
```

Cross apply is similar to `Inner Join`,so you will get only matching rows,`Outer apply` is like `Left join` which will preserve your left table even if there are no matching rows

**update:**

if you want assign default value for outer apply row in case of null,just use IsNull in select

something like below :

```
select *,isnull(b.id,'defaultvalue') from test1 t1 
outer apply(select id from test2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id) b
```

Comment: Thanks it worked like charm. But i want to assign default value as it return `NULL`